# How to enable "larger text" scaling slider on a 2k monitor?

Tags: macos, display, resolution

I have a Mac Mini (late 2014) connected to two Dell U2515H monitors, which have 2560x1440 resolution.

Problem: everything (macOS UI elements) is too small at this native resolution.

I was able to force "HiDPI" mode, using the command below.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true
```

The result looks nice and sharp, BUT everything is too big when using the 1280x720 HiDPI resolution.

What I need is a scaling in between these 2 options (100% and 200%).

It seems that macOS has this option (several levels of scaling available) on their iMacs and MBPs:

[image]

**Is there a trick to enable this slider with my monitors?**

Comment: Apple only does this on their Retina displays, and a few licensed ones. There is a hack for adding HiDPI mode with a terminal command, but it only works with those specific monitors. Sorry!

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I was able to create a 1080p HiDPI resolution using SwitchResX, which I think is equivalent to the built-in scaling shown in the screenshot. Text looks sharp, but overall I'm not happy with how poorly macOS handles my monitor resolution. The scaling is way better on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Search for ResolutionTab on the app store. It's only a couple of bucks and works well on my 2009 MacPro.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review